Installing Multiple EFI Partitions Without Disconnecting Installed Drives
Please do not move this question to SuperUser.  My question relates to EFI partition manipulation, which is not inherent to Windows.
Background
I ran into an issue with UEFI and OS Versions, and I would like some help.  By no means is this an advertisement for my OEM, or a preference for OS'es, but I'm using them to give a thorough description of the issue.  Recently, I found Xidax, an OEM builder for gaming systems.  I also use the system they built for Linux and OS experimentation, besides the gaming. I used to build my own, but age and disability have severely hampered my hand strength and my patience, which is where this issue starts.
Issue
My System is built with a MSI motherboard supporting UEFI, SecureBoot, etc. (fairly recently built).  I've replaced the stock MS Windows UEFI loader with rEFInd.  This EFI boot manager allows me to boot the following OS'es, all on Different Drives:

Windows 11 M2 - 1TB (also where the EFI partition is)
Gentoo Linux
FreeBSD 12 or 13 (which I removed because I hadn't touched or updated it in ages)

Having removed #3, I now have an empty drive (8TB in size), and decided to try something I'd never done.  I have installed Windows 11 on the empty 8TB in hopes of "converting it" into the current AtlasOS. The Windows Installer correctly found the EFI Partition on my M2 Drive and added the Entry to the Windows Loader(WinLoad.efi).  I now have a boot menu based on winloader(the white and blue screen) with 2 choices for Widows 11.
Side By Side versions of  Linux
Forgetting for a moment that this is Windows and remembering I cannot disconnect the First Install to trick the second install into building an EFI partition (due to disability) on the second drive, and using the following scenario:

Replace the Word Windows above with a Linux Distribution

For the sake of this example I'll choose Ubuntu


Install Ubuntu grub version X copy 1 into the only EFI partition
Install Ubuntu grub version X copy 2 into the only EFI partition

Now realizing that I've clobbered the First Installs grub with the second because there is only one ubuntu folder in the EFI partition, I'm stuck as I would like to access both copies independently of each other. For an example of the type of fix I need to implement in a different way, see In rEFInd, need 2 different OS icons for 2 instances of same OS (Ubuntu-MATE).
To do this for Windows/rEFInd, I started with: Booting Multiple Windows Installations from a Third-Party Boot Manager. If you look at the "7 Getting into Windows Went..." steps that is exactly what I have to do to get to either version until I get this fixed.
I'm trying to do this with only 1 EFI Partition, before I use the second answer in Installing rEFInd on Dual Boot Windows 10 Machine (See why I don't want it moved now?).  I'd rather not have EFI partitions all over my drives if I can help it.
Attempted Fix

From a Windows Command Prompt, issued mountvol b: /s.

That worked, I did that the first time I installed rEFInd without access to my Gentoo Install


mkdir b:\EFI\Win10 and mkdir b:\EFI\AtlasOS.

Worked again, but darn their empty and I sure don't want to screw up my EFI partition.


First xcopy /s b:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot b:\EFI\win10

Well shoot, that failed with Sharing Violation.  What?!?! Wait, didn't I run the prompt as Administrator, and isn't my account in the Administrators Group... checking... yes Oh wait Microsoft thinks I'm stupid for wanting to alter the EFI manually on a machine that I OWN. But wait, I can edit it in my Gentoo install so:


Rebooted into Gentoo
Mounted boot
Opened gparted because I never can remember the /dev name for the EFI partition
Mounted the EFI partition to /boot/efi
Cded to /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot
Issued cp -xa . /boot/EFI/Win10 and the same for AtlasOS
Reinstalled grub as I had to boot the kernel directly from rEFInd.

Now I'm finally to the step to alter the BCD, whew back to Windows.  By that time it was 12:30AM last night, and I need sleep, so I decided to come here and ask for advice/help.
Questions
As I said, I'd rather have 1 EFI partition so I'd like to modify that Fix a bit by asking the following:

What are the barebones essentials that need to be in /boot/efi/EFI/{Win10,AltlasOS} in order for the boot to occur cleanly?

cp -xa did in fact replicate xcopy but when I rebooted to start on the BCD I noticed all kinds of files etc. listed on rEFInd's menu.  I don't want to have to hide them all when there are possibly hundreds.


Is there an easier way to split the entries up than the approach I've chosen?
How do I treat an update to the EFI partition in the Future, i.e., will the manual adds need to be readded if Windows Update decides to push an update to the EFI/BCD?


I prefer to have an ESP on every drive. You can use a different name when creating an UEFI boot entry, but need to understand UEFI GUID and files, and ESP entries & folders/files. example UEFI configfile:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/958760/what-does-gpt7-refers-to-in-my-grub-cfg
Compare sudo efibootmgr -v & its GUID/partuuids to lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid Updates to Windows or grub normally change boot order, not names.

I'm providing the approach I used here to save the hassle I went through to other readers who may pass by this page.
Solution I Chose
After struggling nearly 2 weeks including weekends, and finding:

The problem is that third party bootloaders typically create menu entries based on the folders found in the EFI directory.  Because there's only one folder for Windows only one menu item appears.  The trick is to create two separate folders for Windows - each booting a particular version.

And the Note following it:

Note that all this only applies if the second installation of Windows found the original ESP and updated it.  If you disconnect the original ESP drive when you install the second version of Windows it'll create a new ESP on the installation drive and your boot manager should find both when you reconnect the original drive.  In this case you'll automatically get two menu entries.

I decided that I'd use a variation of the approach outlined in Sachithm's answer, even though this was not my original intention.  It's a shame that he doesn't have more answers as this one was thorough and understandable.  I'll list my Approach in order along with a Caveats section that follows.

Delete all the current partitions, and create an empty GPT partition table on the now empty drive used in number 2 below.
Mount an empty HDD/SSD and create 2 Partitions

In this case, one partition was FAT32, and the other was NTFS, but the approach would work with 2 identical Ubuntus say, or a Debian/Arch etc


Label the Partitions

This one is important! Proper labeling of both the FAT32 EFI partition and the new OS'es partition will help prevent user error in the OS installer program. Idiotproof translation: Label your drives/partitions to keep from formatting the installs you want to keep.


Optional But Highly Recommended: When using the same filesystem types for Side-by-Side installs, hide the installs from each other.  See Caveats.
If you did not create 2 Partitions in Step 2, use partitioning software like GParted to resize the partition to create room.  See Caveats
Use the Steps outlined in the Answer I linked, but skip the commands involving shrink.  This is just my personal opinion: I've never trusted Microsoft based tools to manage partition operations without somehow destroying the data within the partitions themselves.

Caveats
I'll list these out as Issue followed by Reason:

RE: 4 - Hiding Partitions

I actually had to perform the procedure outlined above twice.  This may not affect Side-by-Side Linux installs as severely as it does Windows, but thanks to Microsoft's implementation of Security during my first install attempt, in which my installs were not hidden I lost the AtlasOS install after opening it from Windows 11, because of the way the account assigned GUID's cannot intermingle

Once you approve the UAC request to view the new install, you overwrite the new Administrator GUID with the Administrator GUID from your old install.
Note that the new install will boot but everything involving installs or updates will be broken




RE: 5 - Creating Partitions.

Since I could not disconnect drive cables before installing, the Windows Installer used the entire partition the first time (I mistakenly believed that the installer would create a second EFI Partition without intervention, which is why I posted this question.

I write this here just so readers will know to grab more than a cup of coffee.  To reclaim 200MB's to use as an EFI partition on an 8 Terabyte drive took between 37 and 40 hours, using Netboot.xyz, and GParted





